# How to find applicable grid in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have a complex situation, as I am not able to write a single query for this.

I have a table like below:

```
ID  MIN   MAX      PLEVEL
1    0   .50         P1
2    .51   1.00      P2
3    1.01   1.02     P3
```

I have a variable which can have any value like .23, .75 etc

I need query to check the PLEVEL related to this like

```
if variable = .23 than PLEVEL = P1
if varable = .75 than PLEVEL = P2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this to look up the appropriate row in your table for a particular variable. (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/822676/9/0)

```
SET @variable := 0.23;
SELECT @variable, PLEVEL 
  FROM tbl 
 WHERE @variable <= `MAX` AND @variable > `MIN`
```

But, your table data may contain a flaw.  What happens if your variable value is `0.505`? It won't match any row.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't given a lot of detail to go on, but it sounds like you want this:

`SELECT PLEVEL from table WHERE variable >= MIN and variable <= MAX;`

assuming min and max are number columns and you only want plevel returned.

Comment: Thanks you so much

Answer (score 0):

The Immediate If (IIF) statement can be helpful

```
SELECT ID ,IIF(variable=.23,'P1',IIF(variable=.75,'P2','')) as Plevel From MyTable
```

Or you might want to look at the CASE command

Comment: Thanks you so much